# Is $\frac{\left<-y,x\right>}{x^2+y^2}$ conservative on a simply connected region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The vector field $\frac{\left<-y,x\right>}{x^2+y^2}$ is not conservative in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I am wondering if it is on a simply connected region as it satisfies $f_y=g_x$.

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind that the region can never enclose the origin while still being simply connected.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: It can also be not simply connected if its convex hull doesn't include the origin.

Comment: It is also conservative on any subset of any simply connected region in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0$. Basically if your (open, or, say, closure of open) region contains a loop enclosing the origin then $F$ is not conservative on it, if it does not then $F$ is conservative on it.